# Comparing Pivot Table Data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Every month I produce a schedule of forecasted orders for the next 5 years by date and part number. I have sorted the data into a pivot table to show material as the rows with Year, Quarter, Month as the columns and the quantity of the order as the values. I need to compare the differences between the report every month. EXAMPLE: If our forecast is 40 of one part in June 2020 and the next month when we run the report the forecast is for 80 in June 2020, I need to be able to see that difference.

Comment: Is the pivot source data in a single table or is each report generated in a separate table?

Comment: Each report is generated in a separate table

Comment: Can you combine comparative reports into one table?

Comment: No, The data is mostly the same for each month so when I combine the reports and try to do the pivot it combines the data so I am unable to check on the differences

Comment: If you can merge in principle, you can use an additional field to separate reports, such as. "R1", "R2". In any case, you will need to somehow combine the reports in one place so that you can see the differences and pivot table tools will not be enough to do that.